# How to add transform functions from CMSIS DSP library to a Makefile?

Tags: c, makefile, stm32f4, cmsis

I wrote a code that used arm_cfft_f32 function from CMSIS DSP library. How to add CMSIS DSP library to Makefile of my project?

The Makefile generated by STM32CubeMX for STM32F407 chips. I copied .c and .h from CMSIS of statistics, transform and filtering functions folder to my project file in \Src and \Inc.

In the Makefile under C_SOURCES generated by STM32CubeMX I added:

```
Src/arm_cfft_f32.c \
Src/arm_bitreversal.c \
Src/arm_max_f32.c \
Src/arm_cmplx_mag_f32.c \
```

By adding arm_max_f32.c and arm_cmplx_mag_f32.c to Makefile, it compiled without problem. However when I add arm_cfft_f32 in my project. I get this compiling error,

```
PS C:\Radar\Interrupts\Perfect\ADC Interrupts 19\GPIO> make
arm-none-eabi-gcc build/main.o build/gpio.o build/adc.o build/dac.o build/dma.o build/rtc.o build/tim.o build/usart.o build/usb_device.o build/usbd_conf.o build/usbd_desc.o build/usbd_cdc_if.o build/stm32f4xx_it.o build/stm32f4xx_hal_msp.o build/arm_cfft_f32.o build/arm_bitreversal.o build/arm_max_f32.o build/arm_cmplx_mag_f32.o build/stm32f4xx_hal_pcd.o build/stm32f4xx_hal_pcd_ex.o build/stm32f4xx_ll_usb.o build/stm32f4xx_hal_adc.o build/stm32f4xx_hal_adc_ex.o build/stm32f4xx_hal_dac.o build/stm32f4xx_hal_dac_ex.o build/stm32f4xx_hal_rtc.o build/stm32f4xx_hal_rtc_ex.o build/stm32f4xx_hal_tim.o build/stm32f4xx_hal_tim_ex.o build/stm32f4xx_hal_uart.o build/stm32f4xx_hal_rcc.o build/stm32f4xx_hal_rcc_ex.o build/stm32f4xx_hal_flash.o build/stm32f4xx_hal_flash_ex.o build/stm32f4xx_hal_flash_ramfunc.o build/stm32f4xx_hal_gpio.o build/stm32f4xx_hal_dma_ex.o build/stm32f4xx_hal_dma.o build/stm32f4xx_hal_pwr.o build/stm32f4xx_hal_pwr_ex.o build/stm32f4xx_hal_cortex.o build/stm32f4xx_hal.o build/stm32f4xx_hal_exti.o build/system_stm32f4xx.o build/usbd_core.o build/usbd_ctlreq.o build/usbd_ioreq.o build/usbd_cdc.o build/startup_stm32f407xx.o build/arm_bitreversal2.o -mcpu=cortex-m4 -mthumb -mfpu=fpv4-sp-d16 -mfloat-abi=hard -specs=nano.specs -TSTM32F407VETx_FLASH.ld  -lc -lm -lnosys  -Wl,-Map=build/GPIO.map,--cref -Wl,--gc-sections -o build/GPIO.elf
c:/program files (x86)/gnu tools arm embedded/8 2019-q3-update/bin/../lib/gcc/arm-none-eabi/8.3.1/../../../../arm-none-eabi/bin/ld.exe: build/main.o: in function `main':
C:\Radar\Interrupts\Perfect\ADC Interrupts 19\GPIO/Src/main.c:187: undefined reference to `arm_cfft_sR_f32_len1024'
c:/program files (x86)/gnu tools arm embedded/8 2019-q3-update/bin/../lib/gcc/arm-none-eabi/8.3.1/../../../../arm-none-eabi/bin/ld.exe: build/arm_cfft_f32.o: in function `arm_cfft_radix8by2_f32':
C:\Radar\Interrupts\Perfect\ADC Interrupts 19\GPIO/Src/arm_cfft_f32.c:302: undefined reference to `arm_radix8_butterfly_f32'
c:/program files (x86)/gnu tools arm embedded/8 2019-q3-update/bin/../lib/gcc/arm-none-eabi/8.3.1/../../../../arm-none-eabi/bin/ld.exe: C:\Radar\Interrupts\Perfect\ADC Interrupts 19\GPIO/Src/arm_cfft_f32.c:304: undefined reference to `arm_radix8_butterfly_f32'
c:/program files (x86)/gnu tools arm embedded/8 2019-q3-update/bin/../lib/gcc/arm-none-eabi/8.3.1/../../../../arm-none-eabi/bin/ld.exe: build/arm_cfft_f32.o: in function `arm_cfft_radix8by4_f32':
C:\Radar\Interrupts\Perfect\ADC Interrupts 19\GPIO/Src/arm_cfft_f32.c:538: undefined reference to `arm_radix8_butterfly_f32'
c:/program files (x86)/gnu tools arm embedded/8 2019-q3-update/bin/../lib/gcc/arm-none-eabi/8.3.1/../../../../arm-none-eabi/bin/ld.exe: C:\Radar\Interrupts\Perfect\ADC Interrupts 19\GPIO/Src/arm_cfft_f32.c:540: undefined reference to `arm_radix8_butterfly_f32'
c:/program files (x86)/gnu tools arm embedded/8 2019-q3-update/bin/../lib/gcc/arm-none-eabi/8.3.1/../../../../arm-none-eabi/bin/ld.exe: C:\Radar\Interrupts\Perfect\ADC Interrupts 19\GPIO/Src/arm_cfft_f32.c:542: undefined reference to `arm_radix8_butterfly_f32'
c:/program files (x86)/gnu tools arm embedded/8 2019-q3-update/bin/../lib/gcc/arm-none-eabi/8.3.1/../../../../arm-none-eabi/bin/ld.exe: build/arm_cfft_f32.o:C:\Radar\Interrupts\Perfect\ADC Interrupts 19\GPIO/Src/arm_cfft_f32.c:544: more undefined references to `arm_radix8_butterfly_f32' follow
collect2.exe: error: ld returned 1 exit status
make: *** [build/GPIO.elf] Error 1
```

Comment: I added arm_cfft_radix8_f32.c to  C_SOURCES and I left with fallowing: main.c:188: undefined reference to `arm_cfft_sR_f32_len1024'. What does CMSIS defined `arm_cfft_sR_f32_len1024 ?

Comment: I have cfft function defined as fallow, arm_cfft_f32(&arm_cfft_sR_f32_len1024, fft_buffer, 0, 1);

Comment: I relized arm_cfft_sR_f32_len1024 defined in arm_const_structs.c so I added to C_SOURCES. Now I have fallowing error: "build/arm_const_structs.o:(.rodata.arm_cfft_sR_f32_len1024+0x4): undefined reference to `twiddleCoef_1024'" and "build/arm_const_structs.o:(.rodata.arm_cfft_sR_f32_len1024+0x8): undefined reference to `armBitRevIndexTable1024'"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think this might be helpful to someone. 
After adding the fallowing files to the project Makefile it compiled just fine:

```
Src/arm_cfft_f32.c \
Src/arm_max_f32.c \
Src/arm_cmplx_mag_f32.c \
Src/arm_cfft_radix8_f32.c \
Src/arm_const_structs.c \
Src/arm_common_tables.c \
```

The format Makefile was auto generated by STM32CubeMX. In my case, I added CMSIS DSP .c & .h with other files produce by STM32CubeMX for test.  But, it can add in fix directory from CMSIS in your system and reference them in makefile under C_SOURCES and add the header under C_INCLUDES.

Comment: + under ASM_SOURCES, added Src/arm_bitreversal2.s